# Matrix element changes according to index in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I have two functions f(x,y) and g(x,y), where, let say x and y change from x=x0:xt:xN and y=y0:yt:yM (in my real problem these are long vectors). First I want to find minimum of each set, e.g. say Min(i,j)= min(f(x(i),y(j)),g(x(i),y(j))), and then I want to find maximum of all Min(i,j), and also corresponding x(i) and y(j).

Here what I have did. But I understood that it takes long time and PC gets slow for long arrays:

```
x=[2:1:5];
y=[4:2:10];
xl=length(x); 
yl=length(y);
a=zeros(xl,yl);
for j=1:yl
    for i=1:xl
        f=x(i)+y(j); 
g=x(i)*y(j);
        a(i,j)=min(f,g);
    end
end
max(a(:))
```

Here I used two simple functions for f and g, but actual functions are more complicated forms including log functions, etc..

More importantly, I also want to get the corresponding x(i) and y(j).

Can someone help me with simpler/faster code?

```
hvar=0.02:0.02:2.5;
hl=length(hvar);
hfix=1.0*ones(1,hl);
a=hvar; 
b=hvar;
output = zeros(hl,3);

step=0.0001;
x=1.001:step:1.999; 
y=0.001:step:0.999;
xl=length(x); 
yl=length(y);

for k=1:hl
    r=zeros(xl,yl);
    for j=1:yl
        for i=1:xl
            L=y(j)*log(1+2*a(k)-(2*a(k)/x(i))); 
            R=y(j)*log(1-a(k)*b(k)*x(i)+(2*a(k)*b(k)/y(j)));
            r(i,j)=min(L,R);
        end
    end
    [output(k,1) ind]=max(r(:));    %val in 1st column
    [p q] = ind2sub(size(r),ind);
    output(k,2)=1.001+(p-1)*step;   %opt x in 2nd column
    output(k,3)=0.001+(q-1)*step;   %opt y on 3rd column
end
save('output');
```

Comment: What sort of sizes are your actual arrays going to be? Can you give a estimate, it might affect the answer, especially for memory usage.

Comment: x and y are time related parameters, I may need step size of 0.0001 when x or y changes at least from 0 to 2.

Comment: What might be the datasizes for `x` and `y`? Also, whether vectorized solutions are possible would depend on the type of function you would be using to get `f` and `g`. So, if possible try sharing the actual functions involved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Brief discussion and Solution Code

You have three huge nested loops, huge as in the loop iterations are a lot. I have gone *full-throttle* on [`vectorization`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) and I ran out of memory with the given large datasizes. So, the best you can do is to get rid of the two innermost loops and keep the outer-most loop with the iterator, `k`.

Thus, the proposed approach after setting up the parameters and inputs would look like this -

```
for k=1:hl
    L1 = bsxfun(@times,log(1+2*a(k)-(2*a(k)./x)).',y); %//'
    R1 = bsxfun(@times,log(bsxfun(@plus,1-ab(k)*x(:),2*ab(k)./y)),y);
    r1 = min([L1(:) R1(:)],[],2);

    [output(k,1), ind] = max(r1);
    [p, q] = ind2sub(size(L1),ind);
    output(k,2)=1.001+(p-1)*step;
    output(k,3)=0.001+(q-1)*step;
end
```

---

### Benchmarking

The full dataset could not be benchmarked, as the typical runtime even for a single iteration of `k` is a lot. So, for the benchmarking to compare runtimes between the proposed and original approaches, I ran the codes for one single iteration: `k = 1` and then for five iterations: `k = 1:5`.
The idea behind using these two cases, is to see how the speedup with the proposed approach might scale up as we increase the number of iterations with the iterator `k`.
The runtimes thus obtained are listed next.

**Case 1: k = 1**

```
--------------------------------- With Proposed Approach
Elapsed time is 1.934156 seconds.
--------------------------------- With Original Approach
Elapsed time is 9.659695 seconds.
```

**Case 2: k = 1:5**

```
--------------------------------- With Proposed Approach
Elapsed time is 10.387461 seconds.
--------------------------------- With Original Approach
Elapsed time is 49.094747 seconds.
```

**Conclusions:** As one can easily notice that there is a speedup of **`~5x`** with the proposed vectorized approach over the original approach and that scales up **linearly** as we increase the loop iterations for `k`.

Comment: Thanks !!! yes, it reduces running time hugely, and also save my time with the same factor :) Thanks again for sharing your expertise..

Comment: @Frey Glad to help on this!!

Comment: @ Divakar, can you please guide me how I can write this equation as Line 3 in your code to get matrix with length(x)* length(y): R1=x*log(1 + (a(k)*b(k)*(1 - 1/y)*(2/x - y))/(1 + b(k)*(1 - 1/y) + a(k)*(2/x - y)))